# Jquery Templates performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-templates

Is this technology intended for small templates or could be used to display large sets of data? Such as tables with 1000 rows and 20 columns?

How does the performance scale for cases such as these? The ideal and clean way to display the data would be to feed JSONified data returned from the Web Service to JQuery Template. It looks sleek in theory but does it fly in practice for large data sets?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends a lot on the browser that does the rendering.  IE6 can be fairly slow (though transferring 1,000 large rows of HTML markup and injecting that into the document is not going to be fast either).

Here's [a jsperf benchmark that generates 1,000 rows of 10 columns and renders it](http://jsperf.com/jquery-templates-performance).  I'm averaging 200-250ms to render the 1,000 rows in Chrome 9.

The more important question should really be: Why in the world are you displaying 1,000 rows at once?  There are always better UX alternatives than that.

Comment: I am going to display around 600 actually. I was asked to display all rows at once without paging specifically. Someone on SO suggested i do something like cache the data received from the web service and display it in chunks as the user scrolls. I am fairly new to Jquery and haven't seen many examples that illustrate that.

Comment: You wouldn't even necessarily need the complexity of updating as the user scrolls.  Just render the visible set of data first and then immediately begin rendering and appending the rest of your data in ~100 row chunks.  Even better, you could start out by requesting only the first visible set of rows from the web service, then immediately request the rest after rendering the first bit.  That should speed up the total time till something's visible too.  The main drawback of doing that is it would continually affect the size of the scroll bar as more rows were appended.

Comment: Thanks Dave, but  am not sure how that would work, isn't Javascript single threaded? The delay for me happens on the looping through the JSON data (from the web service) side, not web service side...so why would I call the web service several times? Wouldn't your way lock the browser?

Comment: XMLHttpRequest requests to the web service are browser-native and do happen asynchronously while JavaScript executes in its single thread.  So, you can pull down a tiny set of the initial data quickly, and begin a request for the next set before you block the browser with rendering the initial set.

Comment: Also, currently I build the tableHtmlString and shove it into a div, so i only touch the DOM once. If I append rows in chunks would it be more DOM touching and hence slower? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Oh I see...can I do that with Jquery's $ajax function? That's what I am using to connect to Web Service.

Comment: If you have an example of what you are talking about using Jquery $ajax, I would love to see it, as I am not quite getting how I would be able to achieve this w/o locking the browser.

Comment: The DOM insertions shouldn't be too big an issue, because they only happen for each group of rows that you render, not every row.  So, probably only a half dozen times or so for your data.  Yes, you can use $.ajax(); once the request begins, that's happening outside of JavaScript's single thread.  I don't have an example handy, sorry.  Sounds like it might make an interesting topic for a blog post there.  I might work on that soon.

Comment: Oh that would be great! For now, i will use onscroll to append chunks of data as the user scrolls down. Most of my sets would be 200-300 rows, I was only taking a 1000 figure as the absolute top max.